# I want to use apache to use a different page's code with a specific url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have been working on this problem for a bit now. I'm new at Apache so I have no idea what I'm doing.

But basically I am trying to detect when a URL that doesn't exist is entered and then output a `index.php` file based on the specific URL.

This is what I have so far

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(example.com)$
RewriteRule ^/?twyyt/(.*) /index.php
```

THE FAKE URL IS AS FOLLOWS

```
https://www.example.com/twyyt/6543
```

When this URL is entered, I would like the website to use the code from `example.com/index.php`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Presumably you have a `RewriteEngine On` directive before this? There is nothing particularly "wrong" here. What happens exactly? Are you getting an error? Undesirable response? A 404? (If a 404 then what is generating the 404? Apache? Or your script?)

Comment: Presumably this is in a `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(example.com)$
> RewriteRule ^/?twyyt/(.*) /index.php
> ```
>
> THE FAKE URL IS AS FOLLOWS
>
> ```
> https://www.example.com/twyyt/6543
> ```

You are requesting `www.example.com`, but checking for `example.com` only in the *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive), so the rule will never trigger.

Otherwise there is nothing particularly "wrong" here. However...

- Unless you are hosting several domains from the same place, then you don't need to explicitly check the requested hostname. (You certainly don't need to *capture* it - with a parenthesised subpattern.)
- Likewise, you don't need to capture the URL-path after `/twyyt/`. (You are not using it.)
- You are missing the `L` (or `END`) flag, so processing will continue through the file. (Important if you have any directives that follow.)

So, the following may suffice:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^twyyt/ index.php [L]
```

In `.htaccess` you don't need the `/?` prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. Likewise, you don't need the slash prefix on the *substitution* string (to rewrite to a file-path, as opposed to a URL-path).

> I am trying to detect when a URL that doesn't exist is entered

This doesn't actually check that the request does not map to a *file*, if that is what you are implying? The above rule internally rewrites all requests of the form `/twyyt/<anything>` to `/index.php`. So any static assets should not also start `/twyyt/`.

However, if you only want to rewrite URLs of the form `/twyyt/<number>` (as in your example) then the regex can be modified accordingly:

```
RewriteRule ^twyyt/\d+$ index.php [L]
```

Or, to specifically check that the request does not map to a file you need a separate *condition*. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^twyyt/ index.php [L]
```